# Regularity of $\mathbb Z/ n \mathbb Z$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, integers, regular-rings

For which values $n$ is the ring $\mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$ regular? We know that when $n$ is prime, this is regular. When $n$ is not square-free, it's not regular because it is not reduced. However, what if $n$ is square-free?

Comment: I suppose, the definition of a regular ring you are using is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196342/zero-is-a-regular-ring-or-it-is-not)? Then also for $n=0$ it is regular, although $n$ is not squarefree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $n$ is squarefree and let $p_1 \cdots p_n$ be a prime factorization of $n$. The Chinese Remainder Theorem implies $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z}$ as rings. Each $\mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z}$ is a field and thus is regular. Products of regular rings are regular, and so $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is regular.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a clean proof. Do you by any chance know what the localization at each prime ideals look like? I suspect they are all fields because it's quite obvious that the unique maximal ideal after localization would be zero.

Comment: By a theorem of Serre, this implies that $\mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z [x_1, \dots, x_d]$ has global dimension equaling $d$. Is that right?

Comment: @Singularity Yes that's correct on both accounts. Regularity for a ring an Artinian ring is equivalent to being a direct product of fields, which is equivalent to saying each localization at a prime (and thus maximal) ideal is a field. And yes, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_d]$ has global dimension $d$ as you say, assuming $n$ is squarefree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer